# flex 4 add button

Tags: flash, actionscript, button

i have this code that doesn't show any error but can't work; can you help me? i just want to place new button on my form:

```
minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.controls.Button;
            function onClick() {
                var button2:mx.controls.Button = new mx.controls.Button();
                button2.x = 100;
                button2.y = 100;
                Form1.addChild(button2);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Form id="Form1" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Button id="button1" label="button1" click="onClick()" />
    </s:Form>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a runtime exception when I tried to run this.

This should do the trick:

```
protected function onClick():void {
var button2:mx.controls.Button = new mx.controls.Button();
//button2.x = 100; These two lines are obsolete because form handles the layout of its children automatically
//button2.y = 100;
Form1.addElement(button2);
}
```

With Spark containers you need to do addElement() instead of addChild();

You can find more information about working with spark components in the adobe livedocs at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7ff9.html

Cheers

Comment: No problem, however if you have Flashbuilder and had debugged the application, you could have spotted the error message yourself.

So remember to debug, it gives you some nice clues about what could be wrong :)